# How do I render conditional styles (React + Sass)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have these classes in my `scss` file:

```
.errorNotice {
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #D85B5F;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;

  .error & {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

And in my `render` function,

```
{this.state && this.state.error ?
     (
     <p className={styles.errorNotice + (this.state.error ? styles.error : '')}>{this.state.error}</p>
     ) :
     null
}
```

This isn't giving me the styles I want though. It's giving me a weird concatenation:

`campaigns-components-WaitlistForm-styles_errorNotice-1X-Ty4campaigns-components-WaitlistForm-styles_error-JNXx2E`

My goal is to display the `errorNotice` with the correct `display` attribute.

Thanks

Comment: You can't combine two objects into one with the `+` operator.

Comment: Thanks Chris. What's the correct way to use both the `errorNotice` and its child `error` classes here?

Comment: Wait, shouldn't you use `className="errorNotice error"`? Plus, if the `<p>` is invisible unless `this.state.error` is truthy, why not `{this.state.error && <p className="errorNotice">{this.state.error}</p>}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string literals to combine strings. In classname you just need the name of the classes.
So with the ` you can start a string literal and inside of `${}` you can run javascript code and return something:

```
   <p className={`errorNotice ${this.state.error ? "error" : ''}`}>{this.state.error}</p>
```

Maybe it's also an option for you to have a look at styled-components(https://www.styled-components.com). IMHO for React projects this is really neat to use and you don't have to create special css-files anymore or take care of classnames.